# произведение меньше n. Python, питон

Tags: python-3.x

Программа запрашивает натуральное число n. Необходимо составить программу, которая будет считывать целые числа до тех пор, пока их произведение не станет не меньше n. Выведите через пробел количество введенных чисел и их произведение.

```
n = int(input())
#s = int(input())
m = 1
c = 0
while m < n:
    s = int(input())
    c += 1
    m *= s
print(c, m)
```

ответы выводит правильно, но не проходит проверку. Говорит:

```
[+] Test #1. OK
[+] Test #2. OK
[ ] Test #3. Wrong answer
[+] Test #4. OK
[+] Test #5. OK

4 of 5 test(s) passed.
```

подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
m = 1
while m < n:
```

как вы думаете, что выведет программа, если ввести n = 0 или отрицательное?

лучше уж так:

```
n = int(input())

c = 0
m = 1

while True:
    s = int(input())
    c += 1
    m *= s
    
    if n < m:
        break
    
print(c, m)
```

кроме того у вас в условии написано "до тех пор, пока их произведение не станет не меньше n", а проверка сделана как

```
while m < n:
```

а если `m = n`?

правильнее было бы

```
while m <= n:
```

Но все равно все упирается в самое первое возражение

Comment: мне казалось я и этот вариант смотрел.. спасибо большое, помогло!